# monitor not bright enough

Tags: windows-7, display, lcd

I have an acer 19in desktop LCD.

I have the brightness all the way up to 100 and contrast at 80. If I increase the contrast it'll look strange and washed out. But comparing websites to my ipad and laptops, it's much darker.

What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: did you use display colour Calibration?-it also effects brithness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im afraid that the ipad and your laptops just have more powerful backlights. A good quality display can be, in part, gauged by it candela output per sq meter
( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candela_per_square_metre ) as well as by its contrast between colors.

So bottom line, you cant really change the quality of a display.
Also some displays loose their brightness over time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have them, go into the colour settings and try adjusting the colour mode/temperature or the individual gains, you may get a bit of an increase in contrast that way without overdriving the image and getting the washed out effect you experienced using the composite contrast.

Also, have a look and see if there are any settings provided by your graphics card that could help.